# Slit column into multiple columns using pyspark 2.4

Tags: python, pyspark

How we can split sparkDataframe column based on some separator like '/' using pyspark2.4

My Column contains :

```
+-------------------+
|           timezone|
+-------------------+
|   America/New_York|
|  Africa/Casablanca|
|      Europe/Madrid|
|      Europe/Madrid|
|                   |
|   Null            |
```

Thanks

Comment: What output do you expect? Two separate columns if the separator exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Creating a dataframe
values = [('America/New_York',),('Africa/Casablanca',),('Europe/Madrid',),('Europe/Madrid',),('Germany',),('',),(None,)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['timezone',])
df.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------+
|timezone         |
+-----------------+
|America/New_York |
|Africa/Casablanca|
|Europe/Madrid    |
|Europe/Madrid    |
|Germany          |
|                 |
|null             |
+-----------------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import instr, split
df = df.withColumn('separator_if_exists',(instr(col('timezone'),'/') > 0) & instr(col('timezone'),'/').isNotNull())
df = df.withColumn('col1',when(col('separator_if_exists') == True,split(col('timezone'),'/')[0]).otherwise(None))
df = df.withColumn('col2',when(col('separator_if_exists') == True,split(col('timezone'),'/')[1]).otherwise(None)).drop('separator_if_exists')
df.show(truncate=False)

+-----------------+-------+----------+
|timezone         |col1   |col2      |
+-----------------+-------+----------+
|America/New_York |America|New_York  |
|Africa/Casablanca|Africa |Casablanca|
|Europe/Madrid    |Europe |Madrid    |
|Europe/Madrid    |Europe |Madrid    |
|Germany          |null   |null      |
|                 |null   |null      |
|null             |null   |null      |
+-----------------+-------+----------+
```

*Documentation:* [split()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) and [instr()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.instr). Note that `instr()` is 1 based indexing. If the substring to be searched is not found, 0 is returned.